# How to retrieve records from User object which has lookup to contact and populate dynamically in Email template

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a scenario where i have to get user records related to the contact and populate it as dynamic content in the email template through Ampscript Code

```
%%[ 
var @ContactTable, @ContactRow, @OwnerTable, @OwnerRow, @Id, @FirstName, @REmail, @RName @LastName, @Email 
set @ContactTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","ID,FirstName,LastName,Email","Id", "=", ID)
set @ContactRow = ROW(@ContactTable,1) 
set @Id = FIELD(@ContactRow,"ID") 
set @OwnerTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("User","Name,Email","Id", "=", @ID) 
set @OwnerRow = Row(@OwnerTable,1) 
set @RName = FIELD(@OwnerRow,"Name") 
set @REmail = FIELD(@OwnerRow,"Email") 
]%%
Your Owner's Name is %%=v(@RName)=%% 
Your Owner's Email is %%=v(@REmail)=%%
```

I tried the above code but still its not populating anything

Note: I tried this using profile management mapping method its working but it is not working when I use Ampscript code

Comment: Hi @Josyula can you please confirm how are you getting the ID within the RetrieveSalesforceObject for Contact. I see it is set as the DE field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what [**@Brad**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/40846/brad-sapkota) mentioned in his comment, you need to verify your lookup keys.  You're also missing a comma after `@RName` in your variable declarations.

```
%%[ 
var @ContactTable, @ContactRow, @OwnerTable
var @OwnerRow, @FirstName, @REmail, @RName
var @LastName, @Email, @id1, @id2

set @id1 = AttributeValue("ID")
output(concat("<br>id1:", @id1))

set @ContactTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","ID,FirstName,LastName,Email","Id", "=", @id)
set @ContactRow = ROW(@ContactTable,1) 
set @Id2 = FIELD(@ContactRow,"ID") 
output(concat("<br>id2:", @id1))

set @OwnerTable = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("User","Name,Email","Id", "=", @id2) 
set @OwnerRow = Row(@OwnerTable,1) 
set @RName = FIELD(@OwnerRow,"Name") 
set @REmail = FIELD(@OwnerRow,"Email") 
]%%
Your Owner's Name is %%=v(@RName)=%% 
Your Owner's Email is %%=v(@REmail)=%%
```